# boost::asio::ip::udp::socket can I force an immediate send or write?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, boost-asio

I'm working on up programme using boost::asio::ip::udp:: socket where I need at certain moment send a buffer to a specific end point with high priority (I need a guarantee that my data was delivered to the end point and I should see it in tcmpdump capture)
My question is about the function boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::send, is it possible that the system cache the data and don't deliver immediately.
With this kind of function.
I have to fflush the socket if i need to send a high priority data ?
Which is the best approach i have to follow it for this use case ?

Thanks :)

Comment: if you need the guarantee of reception, why udp and not tcp?

Comment: UDP doesn't have the Nagle algorithm which combines writes on TCP sockets (and introduces delay in the process).  However, you cannot avoid the possibility that your datagram is queued, in fact it almost certainly has to be.  Setting priority correctly will get your datagram to the front of the queue, but if there's a large packet already being transmitted, yours will have to wait.  "immediately" is a relative concept in software.

Comment: I think I've heard of user-land NIC hardware drivers. It's extremely low-level, but if you *actually need this*, that's the ticket, perhaps with a unikernel application.  However, since you're asking here, 99.9999% says that you don't actually need this, but you just want to reduce latency. By the way, UDP never gives a guaranteed delivery anyways. TCP cannot give that either, but you should be able detect when a packet wasn't acknowledged.

Comment: Indeed TCP is the best solution but i'm sending packet to third party code which is not mine and this code use UDP